# jQuery href replace function not updatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery carousel and wanted to replace the url but it's not working though there was already pre made directory and there was a folder before named as url/tabs/images/example and now I wanted to make that as url/images/properties I tried a lot but the path is not changing can anyone help me out please.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var dir = "../images/big-carousel/";
var first = true;
var className = 'class="item active"';
var fileextension = ".jpg";
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {

            if (first == false) {
                className = 'class="item"';
            }
            var filename = this.href.replace("http:///tabs/", "");

            $("#carousel-66 .carousel-inner").append($("<div " + className + "> <img src=\"" + filename + "\"></div>"));
            alert(filename);
            first = false;
        });
    }
});
```

I just changed the directory name as ../images/properties/ can anyone let me know why it's not changing up?

Comment: please give us html code,it will be easy to know what's going on

Comment: Are you getting anything from alert(filename) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it's attribute.

try like this.

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Or 
with your code it will be like

```
this.attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```